# <p:fileUpload> Change icon

Tags: file-upload, primefaces

I am using Primefaces

I am trying to change the "+Choose" button that appears on the  command I want that the word "choose" does not appear, only the + sign. Without looking bad.

You can see it using this code:

```
<p:fileUpload id="test"></p:fileUpload>
```

**Update:**

I solved the problem by using something similar to this code:

```
<p:fileUpload id="test" label="#{none}"/>
```

Comment: Your title talks about changing the icon, but the actual question is to just show the icon and not the label... You can always try css to hide things...

Answer (score 0):

Hi try using label attribute to change the default text of the button.  use this attribute.

```
<p:fileUpload id="test" label="+"></p:fileUpload>
```

Comment: The + is an icon, not text... So changing the label to "" would be a better suggestion. Otherwise you'd get 2 '+' 'things', one text and one icon